# Primeng Calendar: Do not reject DateTime if Time is missing

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I am using the calendar form PrimeNG. I need to be able to select the time as well so I have set `[showTime]="true"`. So far so good. The component is working fine.

**My problem:**

My users want to be able to use the input field to type a date/time combination and hit enter to apply the change.
However, when omitting the time, the input is completely rejected on blur. I would rather have it set to 00:00 if the input was just a date without a time. How would I do that?

I could not find a way to alter the internal date validation.

Comment: Can you add your code and blur method?

Comment: It is actually a textbook `<p-calendar>`. I just noticed, that there are no variables for inserting a default time or validation function.